# Get a dropbox and textbox values inside table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to do an easy thing. Get the values from one table row onfocus event.
I have this bad practice assignment, to insert into database without button click so I've decided to use onfocus event for last cell in the row.

The problem is that I'm very new to jquery and javaScript so I'm having troubles getting this dropbox and textbox selected and input values into variables which I will pass later to code-behind using Ajax.

Can someone help me with this problem?

To keep it simple this is a HTML for one of the rows, all the others are the same and the table is static:

```
<table class="default-table" id="tblTest">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="client" class='client'>
                <option>Choose client</option>
                <option>Client 1</option>
                <option>Client 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="project" class='project'>
                <option>Choose project</option>
                <option>Project 1</option>
                <option>Project 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>Choose category</option>
                <option>Front-End Development</option>
                <option>Design</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="in-text medium" name="description" />
        </td>
        <td class="small">
            <input type="text" class="in-text xsmall" name="time" />
        </td>
        <td class="small">
            <input type="text" class="in-text xsmall" name="time" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>Choose client</option>
                <option>Client 1</option>
                <option>Client 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>Choose project</option>
                <option>Project 1</option>
                <option>Project 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>Choose category</option>
                <option>Front-End Development</option>
                <option>Design</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="in-text medium" />
        </td>
        <td class="small">
            <input type="text" class="in-text xsmall" />
        </td>
        <td class="small">
            <input type="text" class="in-text xsmall" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And these are the ways I've been trying to get some of the values using jquery, but non of them is working properly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#tblTest td:nth-child(6)").focusout(function (event) {

            var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
            // tr2 use to be value of id attribute for <tr>, but I deleted it because I want to 
            // use same script for each row

            //var time = $('#tr2 td.eq(5) input').text();
            //var client = $('#tr2 td.eq(1)').text();
            var project = ('$td.eq(2) select option:selected').text();
            var overtime = $td.eq(6).text();
        });
</script>
```

How can I get this values? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where is element with id "tr2"?

Comment: @frosdqy Sorry I forgot to delete that. I've tried giving <tr> id, than I realize that it won't be able to get the values for each row like that. Maybe it's better way to use class name if it's possible. I'm gonna delete that now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can something like this:-

```
$("#tblTest td:nth-child(6)").focusout(function () {
    var parentRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    var time = $('input[name="time"]', parentRow).val();
    var client = $('.client option:selected', parentRow).text();
    var project = $('.project option:selected',parentRow).text();
    var overtime = $('input[name="overtime"]', parentRow).val();
    //Similarly you can find other values
});
```

**Note:** I think last you have typed `time` textbox twice so have considered that as overtime.